# Shopify - Is there a way to determine the type of discount code in the api response

Tags: shopify

When discount codes are applied to orders the way they are brought in in an order is a 2 field array, code and amount. Although, in the admin interface a Shopify user can choose whether or not the type of code is an absolute amount, percent, or free shipping.

In the api response is there a way to determine whether the code used was for free shipping or one of the others? This is causing issues with our sync because taxes are handled different in different locations for shipping costs compared to general order line items.

Thank you,
Brandon

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: No, you can't tell the difference.

**Long answer**: Internally, free shipping codes are actually applied to items in the cart up to the value of the shipping method selected, and then the shipping amount is applied on top.

The upshot of this is that there is no difference between the three discount types as stored on Shopify. They're all just dollar amounts taken off the order subtotal. Therefore you can't tell whether the shipping was discounted because it never is.